# Material ui around border hover

Tags: next.js, material-ui, hover

I want it when the text field is on hover and then the text field around a border. I can't set border hove. I am new to material UI. Please anyone help me? How can solve it? This is my all code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const Shipping = () => {
  const Border = styled(Box)(() => ({
    padding: '2',
    marginTop: '60px',
    select: {
        borderColor: 'red',
    },
  }));

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="h5">Shipping Information</Typography>

      <Border>
        <Typography variant="caption" display="block">
          Caeleb Dressel
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="caption" display="block" marginTop="24px">
          +14097575013
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="caption" display="block" marginTop="24px">
          caelebdressel@example.com
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="caption" display="block" marginTop="24px">
          417 Wahignton Ave. Green cove Springg, Plorida 39495
        </Typography>
      </Border>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Shipping;
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you actually want. can you rephrase? some images can help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make show border on hover like this:

```js
const Border = styled(Box)(() => ({
    padding: "2",
    marginTop: "60px",
    border: "1px solid white",
    "&:hover": {
      borderColor: "red"
    }
  }));
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-border-on-hover?file=src%2FShipping.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.